# Ruby Solargraph Snippet Does Not Show Up

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-snippets

I have been trying to help my classmates at Flatiron install Solargraph for their Macbooks but the problem I have been encountering is with IntelliSense / pop up.
It seems to provide the method names, and hoover seems to sometimes work, but the definition/snippet pop up does not appear to the right of it like it's supposed to.

We're using VSCode, I did put a check on use language server and I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the popup with additional info is closed. When you hover over the completion item, a `>` should appear on the right side of the bar. Clicking it should open the popup. It'll stay open for other items until you close it again.